# str.isdigit() causing program to hang

Tags: python

I am trying to use `str.isdigit()` to try and determine a user input. However, when a user inputs a numeric value between the required parameters, the code just hangs. When other inputs are entered, outside of the parameters, the code functions correctly.

The code is:

```
Input_Value = input("Please choose which activity would would like to run:  ")

while True:

    if Input_Value == "8" or Input_Value == "9" or Input_Value == "0":
        Input_Value = input("Please input an 'x' or a number between 1 & 7: ")

    elif len(Input_Value) > 1:
        Input_Value = input("Please input an 'x' or a number between 1 & 7: ")

    elif (Input_Value.isdigit()) == True:
        Choice = int(Input_Value)
        continue

    elif Input_Value == "x" or Input_Value == "X":
        print()
        print("Thank you for taking part. Good bye")
        print()
        exit()

    else:
        Input_Value = input("Please input an 'x' or a number between 1 & 7: ")

if Choice == 1:
    # do something here

elif Choice == 2:
```

No errors appear, and the code worked fine (without catching errors) before I put in the `elif (input_Value.isdigit() == True:`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `continue` you put in the elif branch causes the next iteration of the `while True` loop to be executed. Since nothin changed, the elif branch will be selected again, the `continue` will skip to the next iteration...
Repeating forever, not allowing any other code to execute.

You might be looking for a `break` instead

Comment: Thanks. That resolved the problem. Knew it was something stupid

Answer (score 1):

You put the `input` outside the loop and you have a continue inside the infinite loop. Because of this, the value of `Input_Value` never changes and always does the same thing over and over and over...

Since you also have code outside the loop, I suggest you try `break`instead of `continue`

you might also want to try using:

```
if Input_Value in ["8", "9", "0"]:
```